# Changing my All City Mr. Pink to disc brakes

Tags: brakes, rim-brake

Interested in changing to disc brakes on my bike. I hear they're a lot better, although I am rather new to this sport and this (Mr. Pink) is my first road bike. Any insight on the process of switching or any thoughts that I shouldn't switch the braking would be appreciated.

Comment: I have extensive experience with rim brakes. Compared to my newer disc brake bike, I agree that discs are often better, but the margins are small and/or they mainly appear in some pretty narrow use cases. For example, carbon disc rims are much better than carbon rim brake rims, but how many of us need carbon rims? Discs brake better in the wet, but how many of us routinely ride in the wet? Discs don’t wear the rim down, but how many rims have you actually worn out? (Me: one pair.)

Answer (score 8):

It’s not practical to do this. The frame needs to be built to take disc brakes, and this frame isn’t. In theory, you could find a custom framebuilder who could add the mounting points and reinforcements you’d need, but that would be very expensive. After that, you’d need new wheels and components.

Answer (score 3):

For the money you would spend retrofitting disks to your Mr Pink, you could swap your Mr Pink frame for a Cosmic Stallion frame that is designed for disk brakes. But I say stick with the Mr Pink.  I built a Mr Pink from the frame up and because of the long  brake reach it was hard to find a decent set of calipers that could be used that also had good stopping power, so I understand why you want to find a solution. I used a set of Shimano BR-A550's with Campagnolo Chorus 10 speed levers. The BR-A550's were not expensive, and I believe the BR-R451 is a  very similar modern equivalent, and works very good if used with a decent set of medium pull levers.  Without knowing what bake equipment you have, I bet you can probably get your existing setup to stop as well as any disk setups with a little tuning.

Comment: Hi! I bought the bike fully fitted so It has all the stock parts from all city.